# How using in Ruby's attr_reader and attr_writer for variable @@?

Tags: ruby, variables

Ruby has this way to share instance variables by using keys like

```rb
attr_accessor :v
attr_reader :v
attr_writer :v
```

How using this but for global @@variable object? Each class can uses variable shared with each instance of object. How creating acessor?
Only proper way is

```rb
def zmienna=(a)
 @@zmienna = a
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing in Ruby. But it is not that hard to write your own:

```ruby
class Module
  def mattr_writer(*attrs)
    attrs.each do |attr|
      define_singleton_method(:"#{attr}=") do |val|
        class_variable_set(:"@@#{attr}", val)
      end
    end
  end

  def mattr_reader(*attrs)
    attrs.each do |attr|
      define_singleton_method(attr) do
        class_variable_get(:"@@#{attr}")
      end
    end
  end

  def mattr_accessor(*attrs)
    mattr_reader(*attrs)
    mattr_writer(*attrs)
  end
end

class Foo; end
Foo.mattr_accessor(:bar)
Foo.bar = 42

Foo.bar #=> 42

Foo.bar = 23

Foo.bar #=> 23
```

Or, you could use ActiveSupport, which already provides these methods.

However, since most style guides discourage usage of class hierarchy variables, there is not much point in having accessors for them.